# Route parameters are URL-encoded

Tags: php, lumen

I'm trying out Lumen and I've written my first route:

```
$app->get('hello/{name}', function ($name) {
    return "Hello, $name!";
});
```

The documentation I've read so far doesn't say a word about how the framework approaches HTML-injection so I made a quick test:

```
http://example.com/hello/<u>café
```

... which showed up like this:

```
Hello, %3Cu%3Ecaf%C3%A9!
```

In other words, route parameters are not URL-decoded when they reach my function. Other frameworks I've tried decode everything for you, just as if you were reading from `$_GET`.

Is there an issue with my set-up (Apache/2.4, mod_php and mod_rewrite with the default `.htaccess` bundled with the framework) or that's the expected input?

Comment: Guess? maybe useful? [dealing with percent-encodings in URLs](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/lumen/dealing-with-percent-encodings-in-urls). `Lumen` is based om `Laravel` code.

Comment: @RyanVincent Yes, that's exactly my problem. If I might add a personal note, I don't think I'll use Lumen—it's too complicated to be "micro" and omits to much basic functionality to be "framework".

Comment: There are a _lot_ of `micro frameworks` to try ;-/ Each has there own way of doing things. Each is useful. It is finding one that fits your way of thinking about things that is not simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an intentional bug/feature (see [Route parameters are URL-encoded #238](https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/issues/238) for reference). No idea about the rationale behind the design decision.